# Which Polygons contains the point

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, geometry

I'm using  `geometry::STPointFromText` for getting a point from a text, and using geometry::STGeomFromText for creating my polygon.
Now i have set of polygons of my `Area` in a table with this description :

```
Id       int       PK
Name     varchar
Polygon  varchar
```

Which area contains STPointFromText('POINT(12 31)',4326)?
I need the query for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a computed column to your table that represents the actual geometry object, you can do this in a set-based manner (which should scale a lot better than your cursor-based approach above). Persisting the column is optional, but will prevent the engine from having to create the geometry object on the fly each time the query is run. Something like:

```
alter table [Area] add g as as geometry::STGeomFromText([Polygon], 4326) persisted
DECLARE @point geometry = geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(539749 3953079)', 4326)
select * from [Area] where g.STIntersects(@point) = 1
```

Comment: POINT(539749 3953079) is for example, this field must be variable for my procedure...

Comment: Yes. You'll see that the point is still a variable. The point is to not convert a table's worth of geometry instances at run time and to avoid a cursor.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

```
DECLARE @polygon geometry
DECLARE @selectedId int
DECLARE @point geometry = geometry::STPointFromText('POINT(539749 3953079)', 4326)
DECLARE geo_cur CURSOR FOR 
SELECT geometry::STGeomFromText('POLYGON(('+Polygon+'))', 4326),id FROM Area where Polygon is not null
OPEN geo_cur
FETCH NEXT FROM geo_cur
INTO @polygon,@selectedId

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        IF @polygon.STIntersects(@point) = 1
            BEGIN
                PRINT @selectedId
            END

        FETCH NEXT FROM geo_cur
        INTO @polygon,@selectedId

    END
CLOSE geo_cur;
DEALLOCATE geo_cur;
```

Comment: Blech! That's not going to perform very well if your Area table gets to be any reasonable size. Let's see if we can make that a set-based query.